# console.log of scope gets undefined

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm trying to acces data from a JSON output by logging it in the console but the console says the element is undefined.

I have a controller which has two functions. Both do a http request from TheMovieDB.org database.

The first function does a search query corresponding to the input of the user. This works fine, also the `console.log` works here and I see all the objects returned.

```
.controller('searchCtrl', [

  '$scope', 'movieService', 'createMovie', 'removeMovie', '$http', function($scope, movieService, createMovie, removeMovie,  $http) {

    $scope.search = function() {

      var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
      var service = '/search/movie';
      var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
      var search = $scope.searchquery
      var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
      var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;

      $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

          if (status == 200) {
            $scope.movieList = data.results;
            console.log($scope.movieList)
          } else {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
          }

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        });
    }
```

I then display the results of that search in a template,

```
%ul#showresults
  %li.search_results{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList | orderBy:'-release_date'"}

    .addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
      %span
        Add Movie
    %img.poster{"ng-src" => "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{ movie.poster_path }}"}
    %span.movieID
      {{ movie.id }}
    %span.title
      {{ movie.original_title }}
    %span.release
      {{ movie.release_date }}
```

As you can see I have elemnt with the `addMovie()` function. When a user clicks on this element the `addMovie` function in the same controller as the search function gets triggerd.

```
    $scope.addMovie = function() {

      'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
      // Search for release dates using the ID.
      var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
      var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
      var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
      var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
      var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
      var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

      $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

          if (status == 200) {
            $scope.movieListID = data.results;
            console.log('succes!' + $scope.movieListID)
          } else {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
          }

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        });

    };
```

It takes the ID from the movie the user wants to add and create a http request which does happen. It shows the correct link in the network tab. But the console log says `succes! undefined`. The succes is for the getting the JSON data and the undefined is the scope.MovieListID.

So the question is, why does this `console.log('succes!' + $scope.movieListID)` become undefined?

Comment: There is/are no `data.results` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have opened the api link in browser. The JSON returned does not have root key results.

Change

```
    $scope.movieListID = data.results;
```

to

```
    $scope.movieListID = data;
```

Comment: thanks that does the trick, but I don't know why, Why does the search query work with results and the movie query not?